# "Drawing of data generated by OpenGL or external APIs such as OpenCL, without CPU intervention."

Tags: opengl

I noticed that in the new features listed for OpenGL 4.0 the following is included:

> Drawing of data generated by OpenGL or external APIs such as OpenCL,
>   without CPU intervention.

What functionality exactly is this referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's talking about [ARB_draw_indirect](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/draw_indirect.txt). That functionality, core in 4.0, allows the GL implementation to read the drawing parameters directly from the buffer object. So the parameters you would pass to `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` come from the buffer, not from your Draw call.

This way, OpenCL or other GPGPU code can just write that struct into the buffer. And therefore, they can determine how many vertices to draw.

AMD has a pretty nifty variation of this that allows for [multi-draw functionality](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/multi_draw_indirect.txt).